I am running into an error related to a junit.jar file not found in <classpath> or <modulepath> when trying to run my tests in NetBeans
I have created Unit Tests for a project of mine and when I click "run test" on my test file, the system return this:
C:\Users\Justin Fussell\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\20\executor-snippets\junit.xml:184: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Justin Fussell\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\20\executor-snippets\junit.xml:128: The  or  for  must include junit.jar if not in Ant's own classpath
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds).
I cannot figure it out and I am not sure what I need to do in order to eliminate the problem and have successful unit tests.
I tried installing JUnit through "Properties", and "Add Library", which is where I added JUnit 5 as well as searching for , and  in the build.xml file which is where I noticed that there was no reference to a junit.jar file.

Not an answer though you should consider moving from netbeans. Try this same project on IntelliJ (most popular nowadays) or Eclipse (I'm an eclipse guy). If it is something your teacher is asking you to do, tell them to move on as well. Show him this comment. Here are some sources: https://pypl.github.io/IDE.html https://www.jrebel.com/blog/best-java-ide
